# How to use AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

First time using AutoMapper and I'm have a hard time figuring out how to use it. 
I'm trying to map a ViewModel to my Database Tables.

My ViewModel looks like this...

```
public class AddressEditViewModel
{
    public AddressEdit GetOneAddressByDistrictGuid { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<ZipCodeFind> GetZipCodes { get; private set; }

    public AddressEditViewModel(AddressEdit editAddress, IEnumerable<ZipCodeFind> Zips)
    {
        this.GetOneAddressByDistrictGuid = editAddress;
        this.GetZipCodes = Zips;
    }
}
```

The Mapping I'm trying to use is...

```
CreateMap<Address, AddressEditViewModel>();
```

When I run this test...

```
public void Should_map_dtos()
{
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

I get this error...

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: The following 2 properties on JCIMS_MVC2.DomainModel.ViewModels.AddressEditViewModel
>   are not mapped: 
>   GetOneAddressByDistrictGuid
>   GetZipCodes
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, or rename the property on JCIMS_MVC2.DomainModel.Address.

I'm not sure how I am supposed to map those 2 properties. I would appreciate any direction.  Thanks

Mark

Comment: Please tag with programming language.

Comment: Couple of things. First, AutoMapper expects no-arg ctors on the destination type.  Next, can you post what Address looks like?

Comment: Address a auto-generated LINQ to SQL class created when I dropped the table on the designer... It's a pretty large class... how much of it do want to see? -MARK-

Comment: After doing some more reading this morning I think your telling that I cannot use AutoMapper in this situation because both of the methods in my viewmodel (GetOneAddressByDistrictGuid & GetZipCodes) require a parameter to be passed in and AutoMapper does not support this functionality is that correct?
If this is so what can you suggest?

Comment: Since none of the properties from the source class `AddressEditViewModel` are matching with the properties in the destination class `Address` I suggest to don't use `AutoMapper` at all. Maybe you should create a method `GetAddress()` and build your own `Address` object.

Answer (score 6):

Ok so I can see a few things you are doing that probably won't help.

Firstly this AutoMapper is used to copy Properties in one object to Properties in a diff object. Along the way it might interrogate or manipulate them to get the end result viewmodel in the correct state.

1. The properties are named 'Get...' which sounds more like a method to me.
2. The setters on your properties are private so AutoSetter won't be able to find them. Change these to minimum internal.
3. Use of a parametrized constructor is no longer needed when you use AutoMapper - as you are converting directly from one object to another. The parametised constructor is there mainly to show what is explicitly required by this object.

   ```
   CreateMap<Address, AddressEditViewModel>()
            .ForMember( x => x.GetOneAddressByDistrictGuid , 
                             o => o.MapFrom( m => m."GetOneAddressByDistrictGuid") )
            .ForMember( x => x.GetZipCodes, 
                             o => o.MapFrom( m => m."GetZipCodes" ) );
   ```

What Automapper is really good for is copying from DataObjects into POCO objects, or View Model objects.

```
    public class AddressViewModel
    {
              public string FullAddress{get;set;}
    }

    public class Address
    {
              public string Street{get;set;}
              public string Suburb{get;set;}        
              public string City{get;set;}
    }

    CreateMap<Address, AddressViewModel>()
             .ForMember( x => x.FullAddress, 
                              o => o.MapFrom( m => String.Format("{0},{1},{2}"), m.Street, m.Suburb, m.City  ) );

    Address address = new Address(){
        Street = "My Street";
        Suburb= "My Suburb";
        City= "My City";
    };

    AddressViewModel addressViewModel = Mapper.Map(address, Address, AddressViewModel);
```